# Find duration between two timestamp in different rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
Row#    TaskID  USerID  Status          TImestamp
1       1           A   WorkStarted     2019-04-28 07:23:19.508
2       1           B   WorkStarted     2019-05-28 07:23:19.508 
3       1           C   WorkStarted     2019-06-28 07:23:19.508
4       1           A   WorkFInished    2019-05-28 07:23:19.508
5       1           A   WorkStarted     2019-06-28 07:23:19.508
6       1           A   WorkFInished    2019-08-28 07:23:19.508
```

I have above data where a task is getting created and is picked by user on different timestamp and then marked as finished once its done.

I have to find the duration taken by a user to finish that task i.e. for above scenario I need two records as as task was finished only twice and that too by user A only on different timestamps

```
Row#    UserID  Duration
1       A       1 Day     (Row4timestamp-Row1TImestamp)
2       A       2 Day     (Row6timestamp-Row5Timesamp)
```

Comment: Are they always the inside pair, so will jobs finish in order?  So if we have Start, Start, Finish, Finish,  1 is associated with three and not 4?

Comment: Also is the duration have to be in days?  Do you round, ceiling, or floor to get integer days?

Comment: yes the assumption here is that a user cant start a job until once he is finished and duration can be in hours or minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the previous start time of the job using `last`, and calculate the duration by subtracting the unix timestamps (which will give you the duration in seconds, and then you can transform it to days by dividing by 86400 seconds/day).

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val result = df.withColumn(
    "last_start",
    last(
        when($"Status" === lit("WorkStarted"), $"Timestamp"), true
    ).over(
        Window.partitionBy("TaskID", "UserID").orderBy("Timestamp")
    )
).withColumn(
    "duration_days",
    (unix_timestamp($"Timestamp") - unix_timestamp($"last_start")) / 86400
).filter("Status = 'WorkFInished'").select("UserID", "duration_days")

result.show
+------+-------------+
|UserID|duration_days|
+------+-------------+
|     A|         30.0|
|     A|         61.0|
+------+-------------+
```

Comment: There is a `datediff` function that gives the difference in days: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#datediff

Comment: @blackbishop the OP said in the comments "duration can be in hours or minutes", so I used a more flexible way to calculate the duration. Thanks anyway

Comment: I am sorry but Row# was just to help but actually there is no such column in dataset......NO worries but I ordered by timestamp and results were good .....Many thanks

Comment: @Harshit how about the edited answer? order by timestamp might work.

Answer (score 1):

First set up the problem and just using Pandas

```
import pandas as pd
data = { 'taskID' : [1,1,1,1,1,1],
    'userID' : ['a','b','c','a','a','a'],
    'status' : ['WorkStarted','WorkStarted','WorkStarted','WorkFinished','WorkStarted','WorkFinished'],
    'timestamp' : ['2019-04-28 07:23:19.508','2019-05-28 07:23:19.508','2019-06-28 07:23:19.508','2019-05-28 07:23:19.508','2019-06-28 07:23:19.508','2019-08-28 07:23:19.508']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df
```

which gives

```
    taskID  userID  status          timestamp
0   1       a       WorkStarted     2019-04-28 07:23:19.508
1   1       b       WorkStarted     2019-05-28 07:23:19.508
2   1       c       WorkStarted     2019-06-28 07:23:19.508
3   1       a       WorkFinished    2019-05-28 07:23:19.508
4   1       a       WorkStarted     2019-06-28 07:23:19.508
5   1       a       WorkFinished    2019-08-28 07:23:19.508
```

then do the work

```
dfOut = pd.DataFrame(columns=['taskID','userID','Duration'])

for name, dfSub in df.groupby(['taskID','userID']):
    dfStart = dfSub[dfSub['status'] == 'WorkStarted']
    dfFinish = dfSub[dfSub['status'] == 'WorkFinished']
    dfFinish['matched'] = False
    for indexS, rowS in dfStart.iterrows():
        for indexF, rowF in dfFinish.iterrows():
            if not rowF['matched']:
                temp = { 'taskID' : [rowS['taskID']],
                    'userID' : [rowS['userID']],
                    'Duration' : [(rowF['timestamp'] - rowS['timestamp'])]}
                dftemp = pd.DataFrame(temp)
                dfOut = pd.concat([dfOut,dftemp])
                dfOut = dfOut.reset_index()
                dfFinish.loc[indexF,'matched'] = True
dfOut
```

and get

```
    taskID  userID  Duration
0   1       a       30 days
0   1       a       122 days
```

Comment: Thanks Paul but I was trying to do it in scala and Pandas usually dont help much in distributed computing

Answer (score 0):

Using spark-sql

```
val df = spark.sql(""" with t1 (
 select  1 c1,   1 c2,  'A'  c3, 'WorkStarted'  c4, '2019-04-28 07:23:19.508' c6  union all
 select  2 c1,   1 c2,   'B'  c3, 'WorkStarted'  c4, '2019-05-28 07:23:19.508' c6  union all
 select  3 c1,   1 c2,   'C'  c3, 'WorkStarted'  c4, '2019-06-28 07:23:19.508' c6  union all
 select  4 c1,   1 c2,   'A'  c3, 'WorkFInished'  c4, '2019-05-28 07:23:19.508' c6  union all
 select  5 c1,   1 c2,   'A'  c3, 'WorkStarted'  c4, '2019-06-28 07:23:19.508' c6  union all
 select  6 c1,   1 c2,   'A'  c3, 'WorkFInished'  c4, '2019-08-28 07:23:19.508' c6
  )  select   c1  Row,   c2  TaskID,   c3  USerID,   c4  Status,   cast(c6 as timestamp) TImestamp    from t1
""")
df.show(50,false)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")

+---+------+------+------------+-----------------------+
|Row|TaskID|USerID|Status      |TImestamp              |
+---+------+------+------------+-----------------------+
|1  |1     |A     |WorkStarted |2019-04-28 07:23:19.508|
|2  |1     |B     |WorkStarted |2019-05-28 07:23:19.508|
|3  |1     |C     |WorkStarted |2019-06-28 07:23:19.508|
|4  |1     |A     |WorkFInished|2019-05-28 07:23:19.508|
|5  |1     |A     |WorkStarted |2019-06-28 07:23:19.508|
|6  |1     |A     |WorkFInished|2019-08-28 07:23:19.508|
+---+------+------+------------+-----------------------+


spark.sql("""
select userid, duration_days/86400 duration_days from (
select *, unix_timestamp(lead(timestamp) over(partition by userid order by row)) - unix_timestamp(timestamp) duration_days from df
)
where status='WorkStarted' and duration_days is not null
order by userid, row
""").show(false)

+------+-------------+
|userid|duration_days|
+------+-------------+
|A     |30.0         |
|A     |61.0         |
+------+-------------+
```